# Detect a collision with the edge of a circle

Tags: javascript, math

I am using a script to generate random particles within a circle based on it's radius.  What I would like to do next is detect when the particle collides with the circles edge.

I'm guessing I need to use a for loop to store the coordinates of the circles circumference in an array but I'm unsure what math is needed to do this.

Here's what I've got down from the answer below.  It doesn't seem to be working though:

Variable par is a particles moving with the circle, emitters contains x,y, positions of the centre of the circle while the prop height contains the radius.

```
var fromC = Math.sqrt( (par.y-(emitters[i].y ) )^2 + (par.x- (emitters[i].x))^2); 

if(fromC >= emitters[i].height){
    par.vx *= -1;
    par.vy *= -1;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know the center of the circle and the radius you could just check the distance from the center.

Comment: You have to compare with the radius of the circle.

Comment: Please provide info on the variables `par` and `emitters`.

Comment: @ATOzTOA emitters[i].height is the radius.

Comment: Can you try adding a `alert` inside the `if`?

Comment: @ATOzTOA Updated with variable info.  It's definitely firing, just not when the particles hit the circles edge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [circle-circle collision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736734/circle-circle-collision)

Comment: Also have a look at all the other [circle collision-detection questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bcollision-detection%5d%20circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `square` operation, `^` is NOT power operator in javascript.

Use this:

```
var fromC = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((par.y - emitters[i].y), 2) + Math.pow((par.x - emitters[i].x), 2) ); 

if(fromC >= emitters[i].height){
    par.vx *= -1;
    par.vy *= -1;
}
```

Comment: No joy, seems to be throwing lots of NANs.

Comment: `NaN`s? How is that possible with a positive root argument? Are you absolutely sure all parameters are correctly initialized? Try `console.log()`ging the `par` and `emitters[i]` objects.

Comment: Here's what I'm getting going fromC em.y em.x em.height par.y par.x : NaN 306.5 338.5 190.85 433.2453792351848 333.1283476399258 .

Comment: Can you print fromC without the Math.floor?

Comment: Without Math.floor : NaN 306.5 338.5 260.6 31.176133123692125 580.35272803111

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: Are you printing the values using the code in your question or the one in my answer?

Comment: Got you, still getting NaNs with the original: NaN 306.5 338.5 201.9 617.4620188029949 110.25046234992328

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the distance between the point and the center of the circle (  square root( (y2-y1)^2 + (x2-x1)^2)  and compare with the radius

Comment: Thanks, I've added some code to my question based on the answer.  It isn't working though, could you give it a look.