# How to do intersection with condition in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, collision-detection, conditional-statements, intersection

I have a question about intersection or rather collision detection with condition. I am doing a collision detection between a bar(Image) and a ball(Image). The bar can be moved up and down upon user's response on dragging the bar. The collision detection codes are as below.

```
public bool Intersects(Rect barRectangle, Rect blueBallRectangle)
    {
        barRectangle.Intersect(blueBallRectangle);

        if (barRectangle.IsEmpty)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In private void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)

```
Rect blueBallRectangle= new Rect(blueBallPositionX, blueBallPositionY, blueBall.ActualWidth, blueBall.ActualHeight);
Rect barRectangle= new Rect(barPositionX, barPositionY, bar.ActualWidth, bar.ActualHeight);
```

For the time being, when the ball detect the collision then it will deflect away. However, I want to add on to it that it will go through the gap rather then deflecting away.

```
if (Intersects(barRectangle, blueBallRectangle))
        {
            this.blueBallVelocityY *= -1;
            this.blueBallVelocityX *= -1;
        }
```

The image of the bar is as below.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using a physics engine like farseer ([codeplex](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/), [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages?q=farseer))

Comment: @ShawnKendrot For your info, I am not allowed to use such engine as my lecturer told me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should use two bounding boxes to describe the red bar: one on top, and one on bottom.  Then your code can check to see if the blue ball intersects with *either* one.  In this case, if the ball fits between the two barriers, it will not intersect with either one, and the ball will carry on merrily forward (whereupon the player will presumably die).

Incidentally, the snippet:

```
if (barRectangle.IsEmpty)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

can be replaced with simply:

```
return !barRectangle.IsEmpty;
```

Comment: I am sorry but I forgot to mention something. The bar is enabled to move up and down depends on the user's response. I used GestureService.GestureListener and MouseDragElementBehavior.

Comment: That's fine.  The bounding boxes will move every frame (along with the ball), and the suggested solution still works.

Comment: Okay. The bar is a whole image and its under the MouseDragElementBehavior. May I know what do you meant by bounding boxes?

Comment: I just mean the rectangles representing your two red bars.