# Glancing collision between circles

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, collision-detection, physics

I am modelling objects in a game prototype as circles. Each object has a mass, radius, velocity, and location. No two objects have the same mass and radius.

I have to following code which is supposed to calculate an elastic collision between them, but I've noticed that the results are always as if the circles had hit each other dead-on.

```
private void handleCollision(JumpObject a, JumpObject b) {
        double newVelAX = (a.getVelocity().x * (a.getMass() - b.getMass()) + (2 * b.getMass() * b.getVelocity().x)) 
                / (a.getMass() + b.getMass());
        double newVelAY = (a.getVelocity().y * (a.getMass() - b.getMass()) + (2 * b.getMass() * b.getVelocity().y)) 
                / (a.getMass() + b.getMass());
        double newVelBX = (b.getVelocity().x * (b.getMass() - a.getMass()) + (2 * a.getMass() * a.getVelocity().x)) 
                / (a.getMass() + b.getMass());
        double newVelBY = (b.getVelocity().y * (b.getMass() - a.getMass()) + (2 * a.getMass() * a.getVelocity().y)) 
                / (a.getMass() + b.getMass());

        a.getVelocity().setLocation(newVelAX, newVelAY);
        b.getVelocity().setLocation(newVelBX, newVelBY);
}
```

I need to deal with the case where one of the circles hits another at a glancing angle (I can do a diagram later if it's needed), such as when a small circle just barely nicks the edge of a larger circle as it goes by.

How do I modify my collision algorithm to account for *where* one circle hits the other?

Comment: You need `atan2`, along with the distance between centers.

Comment: Are you up for some physics? It's almost impossible to get the code working without understanding the physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the references.

[circle-circle collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736734/circle-circle-collision)

[Ball to Ball Collision - Detection and Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345838/ball-to-ball-collision-detection-and-handling?rq=1)

http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions/

http://processing.org/examples/circlecollision.html

Comment: These are good references. The third one, at gamedev.tutsplus, actually reproduces exactly the problem I'm having. If you watch their last demo running, you'll notice that glancing collisions do the same thing as direct ones. Processing's circle collision code seems to have the stuff I need.

Comment: My final solution involved importing a `Vector2D` class to handle some of the math. I can figure out the vector math, but doing all the trig as well was getting me mixed up.

Comment: @MartinCarney Looks like the problem with the simulation at gamedev.tutsplus has been fixed.