# Resolving a Circle-Circle Collision

Tags: math, geometry, collision-detection

I am writing software that extends [Circle-Rectangle collision detection (intersection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection) to include responses to the collision. Circle-edge and circle-rectangle are rather straight-forward. But circle-circle has me stumped.

For example, let two circles collide, one red and one green, in a discrete event simulation. We might have the following situation:

[image: Two Circles Colliding]

Immediately after they collide we could have:

[image: Enlarged Circles Collision]

Here RIP and GIP were the locations of the circles at the previous clock tick. At the current clock tick, the collision is detected at RDP and GDP. However, the collision occurred between clock ticks when the two circles were at RCP and GCP. At the clock tick, the red circle moves RVy downward and RVx rightward; the green circle moves GVy downward and GVx leftward. RVy does not equal GVy; nor does RVx equal GVx.

[image: Circle-Circle Computation]

The collision occurs when the distance between the circle centers is less than or equal to the sum of the circles' radii, that is, in the preceding figure, d <= ( Rr + Gr ). At a collision where d < ( Rr + Gr ), we need to position the DPs back to the CPs before adjusting the circles' velocity components. In the case of d == ( Rr + Gr ), no repositioning is required since the DPs are at the CPs.

This then is the problem: how do I make the move back to the CPs. Some authors have suggested that one-half of the penetration, given by p in the following figure, be applied.

[image: Penetration]

To me that is just plain wrong. It assumes that the velocity vectors of the two circles are equal that, in this example, is not the case. I think penetration has something to do with the computation but how eludes me. I do know that the problem can be recast as a problem of right similar triangles in which we want to solve for Gcdy and GCdx.

[image: Right Similar Triangles]

The collision itself will be modeled as elastic, and the math for the exchange of inertia is already in place. The only issue is where to position the circles at collision.

Comment: What kind of collision are you looking for?  Elastic (no loss of energy)?  Inelastic (loss of energy)?  The two circles stick together and continue moving as a pair?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics and not programming.

Comment: @john The collision will be modeled as elastic. The math for the exchange of inertia is already in place. The problem is where to position the circles.

Comment: @tom10 The problem is related to programming a simple discrete event animation. Positioning the circles after the collision will be incorporated into the animation.

Comment: @Gus: just because it will eventually be used in a program does not make the question about programming.  The question is **about** physics, and the result will be used in a program.

Comment: Getting started in this area is hard.  Truly good examples of how to get started with collision responses are few and far between. Until you've done it, it's very hard to distinguish what who (and what) should spend time reading / implementing. The issue is further muddied by alternative methods suitable for different problem domains. The question isn't perfect - but stackoverflow is the only place in the network (except maybe scicomp.stackexchange) with an audience capable of providing an answer for the author.

Comment: A careful reading of the Question and the OP's Comments leads me to the conclusion that the problem is simply one of circle-circle collision detection, slightly complicated by unequal radii and velocity components.  As such there are many SO posts in this general topic, and if there's an argument to be made for closing, it seems more likely one will find a duplicate than to successfully argue for its exclusion on subject matter grounds.

Comment: See for example [this 2009 Question about locating circle-circle collisions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736734/circle-circle-collision), which has a highly-upvoted (but not Accepted) Answer.

Answer (score 4):

"This then is the problem: how do I make the move."

It is likely that you want to know how "to position the DPs back to the CPs before adjusting the circles' velocity components."

So there are two issues, how to determine the CPs (where the collision occurs) and how to adjust the circles' motion going forward from that point.  The first part has a rather easy solution (allowing for different radii and velocity components), but the second part depends on whether an elastic or inelastic response is modelled.  In a Comment you write:

> The collision will be modeled as elastic. The math for the exchange of inertia
>   is already in place. The problem is where to position the circles.

Given that I'm going to address only the first issue, solving for the exact position where the collision occurs.  Assuming uniform motion of both circles, it is sufficient to know the exact time at which collision occurs, i.e. when does the distance between the circles' centers equal the sum of their radii.

With uniform motion one can treat one circle (red) as motionless by subtracting its velocity from that of the other circle (green).  In effect we treat the center of the first circle as fixed and consider only the second circle to be in (uniform) motion.

Now the exact time of collision is found by solving a quadratic equation.  Let V = (GVx-RVx, GVy-RVy) be the relative motion of the circles, and let P = (GIPx-RIPx,GIPy-RIPy) their relative positions in the "instant" prior to collision.  We "animate" a linear path for the relative position P by defining:

P(t) = P + t*V

and ask when this straight line intersects the circle around the origin of radius Rr+Gr, or when does:

(Px + t*Vx)^2 + (Py + t*Vy)^2 = (Rr + Gr)^2

This is a quadratic equation in unknown time t, all other quantities involved being known.  The circumstances are such that (with collision occurring at or before position CP) a positive real solution will exist (typically two solutions, one before CP and one after, but possibly a grazing contact giving a "double root").  The solution (root) t you want is the earlier one, the one where t (which is zero at "instant" RIP,GIP positions) is smaller.

Comment: hi good morning thx for the info. ive been trying to implement this but could really use some advice, any ideas? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/201599/javascript-top-down-circle-to-circle-smooth-collision-detection

Comment: I took a look at your linked Question at GameDev.SE, but I can't tell what you are asking. It is a burden but to ask a good Question, one needs to separate out what data is given (the setup) and what result is wanted (the goal).  These may be obvious to you, but Readers needs to have it written out for them.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I'm essentially trying to make sliding movement, like in mmorpgs when the character intersects with an object and slides off of it as moving, if that makes sense. Trying to do it for circle collisions atm

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a basic reference on inelastic collisions for circular objects, [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php) by  Joe van den Heuvel and Miles Jackson is very easy to follow.

From least formal to most formal, here are some follow up references on the craft of implementing the programming that underpins the solution to your question (collision responses).

- Brian Beckman & Charles Torre [The Physics in Games - Real-Time Simulation Explained](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Brian-Beckman-The-Physics-in-Games-Real-Time-Simulation-Explained)
- Chris Hecker, [Physics, Part 3: Collision Response](http://chrishecker.com/images/e/e7/Gdmphys3.pdf), Game Developer 1997
- David Baraff, [Physically Based Modeling: Principles and Practice](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~baraff/sigcourse/), Online Siggraph '97 Course notes, of particular relevance are the Slides for rigid body simulations.

You're going to have to accept some approximations - Beckman demonstrates in the video that even for very simple cases, it isn't possible to analytically predict what would occur, this is even worse because you are simulating a continuous system with discrete steps.

Answer (score 2):

To re-position the two overlapping circles with constant velocities, all you need to do is find the time at which the collision occurred, and add that factor of their velocities to their positions.

First, instead of two circles moving, we will consider one circle with combined radius and relative position and velocity.  Let the input circles have positions `P1` and `P2`, velocities `V1` and `V2`, and radii `r1` and `r2`.  Let the combined circle have position `P = P2 - P1`, velocity `V = V2 - V1`, and radius `r = r1 + r2`.

[image]

We have to find the time at which the circle crosses the origin, in other words find the value of `t` for which `r = |P + tV|`.  There should be 0, 1, or 2 values depending on whether the circle does not pass through the origin, flies tangent to it, or flies through it.

`r^2 = ||P + tV||` by squaring both sides.

`r^2 = (P + tV)*(P + tV) = t^2 V*V + 2tP*V + P*P` using the fact that the L2-norm is equivalent to the dot product of a vector with itself, and then distributing the dot product.

`t^2 V*V + 2tP*V + P*P - r^2 = 0` turning it into a quadratic equation.

If there are no solutions, then the discriminant `b^2 - 4ac` will be negative.  If it is zero or positive, then we are interested in the first solution so we will subtract the discriminant.

```
a = V*V
b = 2 P*V
c = P*P - r^2
t = (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / (2a)
```

So `t` is the time of the collision.

Comment: One more thing.  Depending on your code, it is possible that if two overlapping objects are repositioned and their velocities are changed as per usual - but they are not repositioned quite far enough - then they instantly collide again and warp across the map due to their already altered velocities.  To prevent this, it would be best to use floating point numbers in such a way that they are rounded in the correct direction, but I don't know how to do that so I just multiply `t` by some `1+epsilon`.

Comment: I cant seem to make this solution work. I'm calculating t and then multiplying velocities by it, and adding the resulting vector to their positions. Was that the idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually derive an expression for the time required to reach a collision, given initial positions and velocity vectors.

Call your objects A and B, and say they have position vectors **a** and **b** and velocity vectors **u** and **v**, respectively. Let's say that A moves at a rate of **u** units per timestep (so, at time = t, A is at **a**; at time = t + 1, A is at **a** + **u**).

I'm not sure whether you want to see the derivation; it wouldn't look so great... my knowledge of LaTeX is pretty limited. (If you do want me to, I could edit it in later). For now, though, here's what I've got, using generic C#-ish syntax, with a Vector2 type that is declared Vector2(X, Y) and has functions for vector addition, scalar multiplication, dot product, and length.

```
double timeToCollision(Vector2 a, Vector2 b, Vector2 u, Vector2 v)
{
    // w is the vector connecting their centers;
    // z is normal to w and equal in length.
    Vector2 w = b - a;
    Vector2 z = new Vector2(-1 * w.Y, w.X);
    Vector2 s = u - v;
    // Dot() represents the dot product.
    double m = Dot(z, s) / Dot(w, s);

    double t = w.Length() / Dot(w, s) * 
              (w.Length() - sqrt( ((2 * r) ^ 2) * (1 + m ^ 2) - (m * w.Length()) ^ 2) ) / 
              (1 + m * m)

    return t;
}
```

As for responding to collisions: if you can fast-forward to the point of impact, you don't have to worry about dealing with the intersecting circles.

If you're interested, this expression gives some cool results when there *won't* be a collision. If the two objects are moving away from each other, but would have collided had their velocities been reversed, you'll get a negative value for t. If the objects are on paths that aren't parallel, but will never meet (passing by each other), you'll get a negative value inside the square root. Discarding the square root term, you'll get the time when they're the closest to each other. And if they're moving in parallel at the same speed, you'll get zero in the denominator and an undefined value for t.

Well, hopefully this was helpful! I happened to have the same problem as you and decided to see whether I could work it out on paper.

**Edit**: I should have read the previous responses more carefully before posting this... the mess of a formula above is indeed the solution to the quadratic equation that hardmath described. Apologies for the redundant post.